# Trying to fix reading from file C#

Tags: c#

I have made a small console application, works fine other than when I enter a pin, will include some code soon, I can enter part of it and it will still log me in, I do not want it to do this, I need the pin to be exact to log in.

Full code can be accessed here: https://pastebin.com/ARX1MqLc

```
Console.WriteLine("Please insert your credit card by pressing 'Enter'.");
Console.ReadKey();
Console.Write("Please enter your 4-digit PIN: ");
pin = Console.ReadLine();
bool pinVerif = File.ReadAllText("C:/Users/ryanj/OneDrive/Documents/Random code/myApp/pin.txt").Contains(pin);
if(pinVerif == true)
{
    verified();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry your PIN was incorrect, please try again or exit the program.");
    menu();
}
```

I did create a file that is called pin.txt, so you will need to create that and put anything in it, but I honestly don't know whats wrong with it.

Comment: Change `Contains` to `Equals` if you want to match exactly.

Comment: Read all the text into a string variable.  Then do you test in a second step.  That way you can find out where your problem is using the debugger.

Comment: @Flydog57 i am using visual studio code and dotnet in cmd to run program

Comment: I use VS.  Doesn't VS Code come with a debugger?  Debugger's are essential.

Answer (score 0):

You need an exact match in this case:

```
string pinContent = File.ReadAllText("C:/Users/ryanj/OneDrive/Documents/Random code/myApp/pin.txt");

bool pinVerif = (pin == pinContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the way contains works. It compares the string you entered with the whole string and checks to see if that part is in there.

Their are tons of ways to solve this. The easiest is to check if the length of your pin is 4.

```
if(pinVerif && pin.length==4)
```

or you could do something more complicated and use i.e. json to store the pins in seperate object.

Comment: I didnt realise that `contains` would compare, i have changed it to `equals` now and it works thank god

Comment: Keep in mind that that with equals your pin.txt has to match the entered pin fully. So your current solution won't work if you have more than one pin in your pin.txt